# pushing to array using arrayFiilters

Tags: mongodb

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("626398403905f04f59db38c7"),
    "username" : "erkin",
    "email" : "erkin-07@hotmail.com",
    "password" : "b",
    "playlists" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 58,
            "name" : "asdsa",
            "date" : "09-01-15",
            "musics" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "INNA - Cola Song (feat. J Balvin)",
                    "duration" : "3.00"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "blabla",
                    "duration" : "3.00"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 59,
            "name" : "asdsa",
            "date" : "09-01-15",
            "musics" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "INNA - Cola Song (feat. J Balvin)",
                    "duration" : "3.00"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "blabla",
                    "duration" : "3.00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I trying to push document playlist.music with id of 58

```
db.getCollection('playlist').updateOne({},
  {$push:{"playlists.$[outer].musics":{name:'shiva',duration:'7.00'}}},
  {$arrayFilters:[{"outer._id":58}]}
)
```

but it throws error:

> "No array filter found for identifier 'outer' in path
> 'playlists.$[outer].musics'"

Comment: `arrayFilters` not `$arrayFilters`.

Comment: @Yong Shun yes..., working.